# Use include tag to include the same template that is calling it

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a use case where different fields of a form are rendered differently based on an `include` tag and arguments passed to it. To keep it DRY, sometimes I'd like to include the same template and pass it a different argument, like in a simplified example below:

main_form.html

```
{% include "./field-snippet.html" with type=list %}
```

field_snippet.html

```
{% include "./field-snippet.html" with type="regular" %}
```

But that gives the following `TemplateSyntaxError`:

```
The relative path '"./field-snippet.html"' was translated to template name 'myappname/field-snippet.html', the same template in which the tag appears.
```

Alternatively, I could have different html files for different kinds of fields but that seems to be many files with not much code in each. Any ideas on how to best approach this? Is using custom `Widgets` the best approach here (I haven't played much with them yet)

Comment: You certainly don't need the `./`. But you should show the full error.

Comment: @DanielRoseman updated the question with the error statement

Comment: @DanielRoseman I tried removing `./` but got a `TemplateDoesNotExist` error

Answer (score 1):

This is more of a workaround than an answer, but using an absolute path avoids this error.

```
{% include "YourApp/field-snippet.html" with type="regular" %}
```

I assume the devs had a good reason for this error, so use at your own risk. [The docs discuss using the same name with `{% extends %}`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/overriding-templates/#extending-an-overridden-template), but I haven't fount any mention of recursive `{% include %}`.